# DIY generator does not generate electricity

Tags: generator

I am doing a school project and it would be great to have some help. I have built a small generator using a pringles can and enameled copper wire, but when I spin the magnet inside, the voltmeter I am using does not show any constant increase in AC voltage. The meter is not the problem as it is brand new and was around $80. I  have tried spinning both with the direction of the wires and against it, and got nothing.

Comment: Please add a schematic and pictures. My crystal ball is not working today.

Comment: Another thing to clear up - how fast are you spinning the magnet? If you're doing it by hand the frequency will be too slow for a meter to show on AC, but you can probably see it on the DC scale.

Comment: Note that, with everything else designed right, you still need a few hundred turns of enamel magnet-wire to generate a few volts.  Not ten or twenty turns: 500-800 turns is good.  (But when using big neo supermagnets, only need 50 turns!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your magnet is too short?   The poles of the magnet must be very close to the copper wire.  If a small magnet is spinning inside a large pringles can, the generator won't work.

Or, maybe the magnet is spinning wrong.   To act as a generator, the magnet poles must flip end-over-end, so the poles are sweeping *across* the loop of wire.

If instead the magnet poles are sweeping *along* the wire, then the generator won't work.  (The magnet poles must not travel around and around the circular pringles can, instead they have to sweep into the can and out, with the axle of the magnet assembly poking through the cardboard can, sticking through the coil of wire.)   Or, if the magnet poles aren't sweeping in a **biiig** circle through space (if the magnet only spins on axis, with poles barely moving,) then the generator won't work.   Or finally, if two or more magnets were stacked with opposite poles too close together, then the fields are canceled out, and the generator won't work.

Here's [a similar generator project](https://youtu.be/3P50nXFOHCQ), with the wire wound on a plastic ring.  See how the neo supermagnets are flipping end-over-end?  Notice that the ends of the magnet are moving quite close to the copper wire.  And, the magnet sweeps *across* the copper wire.  Not along it.

Here's my [entire debugging section](http://amasci.com/coilgen/generator_3.html) for this type of ultra-simple generator.

Hint: instead of a voltmeter, wind 600 turns or more of thin #30 wire, then hook the ends to a red LED, and the LED will flash as the magnets spin.

PS
Beware of online projects which don't work, where the author never bothered to test or even build the device they show!  For example, [wikiHow diagrams and instructions are wrong](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Simple-Electric-Generator), while [Instructables version works fine](http://www.instructables.com/id/Electric-Generator-Powering-LEDs/).

Answer (score 1):

> when I spin the magnet inside, the voltmeter I am using does not show
>   any constant increase in AC voltage.

Here's one way to generate voltage with a magnet and a coil: -

[image]

Notice that the voltage rises as the magnet enters towards the coil and as the magnet is removed, the coil voltage is negative. Also note that when the magnet reaches the stationary position when fully inserted, the voltage drops to zero.

What is important is that the coil is subject to a changing magnetic field; the intensity rises as the magnet enters the coil and drops in intensity as the magnet exits the coil. It is therefore a change of magnetic flux that gives rise to a voltage induced in a coil.

You can achieve the same thing if the magnet is spinning relative to the coil like this: -

[image]

However, if you were to rotate the spinning axis through 90 degrees so that the magnet rotated in the horizontal plane, the voltage output would be close to zero. Some voltage would be induced in the "turns" at the extreme ends of the coil but no voltage would be induced in the turn at the coils mid-point.

In your experiment, I suspect you are not rotating the magnet in the correct plane relative to the coil and this will produce zero or low voltages.

Answer (score 0):

The cardboard part of pringles cans has metal inside, which could make it conductive. If the enamel wire is wound around a conductive can the current may travel through the can instead of through your wire.